# Modifying my theme's template.php requires apache restart to see changes

Tags: 7, caching

When I make modifications to my .tpl.php file, I assure that changes are "reloaded" by executing "drush cc all".

But when I change my template.php file, the only way I have to see the output of my new code, such as adding a simple dpm($form) statement, is by restarting apache.

I've tried:

- drush cc all
- Devel module -> Clear cache.
- Configuration -> Performance -> Clear all caches.
- Check that in Configuration -> Performance -> CACHING -> disabled.
- Clear browser cache.
- Test it in a different browser.

But the changes only appear when I issue /etc/init.d/httpd restart.

Any idea of why?

Comment: You probably have some sort of apache-/server-level caching going on. mod_cache maybe? reverse proxy? can't really say from here

Comment: Also check if apc.stat=0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Clive and MPD, that pointed to the answer.

It was because of APC.

I've installed the module apc_admin, which allows to access the APC interface (apc.php) from within drupal (Configuration » Development » Performance » APC).  That includes the "**Reset APC cache**" button. Just by pressing it, the changes in my template will show up.

Hope this helps also other users.